# Spring JSP remains cached

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jquery-mobile, spring-mvc

I have a problem with a servlet i'm working on. It's a site for mobile devices on spring framework, using Java and JQuery Mobile, deployed under weblogic. I use the same jsp for an app inside the site which may be different in case of different user roles / logged in - logged out users etc. If i log in and click on the button to the app, it looks correctly. I submit a wrong form, let's say, and a div with an error message appears on top. I click on home, then if i log out or not, then click again on the button, the page comes cached and the error is still displayed. The controller won't be accessed again, only if i input myself the request in the address bar.

Any idea what would be the problem ? I tried response.setHeader with no-cache and other solutions to disable browser caching, because this seems to be the problem, but none seems to work.

My app flows something like this:
When the button from the homepage is clicked, the request calls the controller which verifies if you are logged in or not, then returns the jsp like:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/recharge",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String render(org.springframework.ui.Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    ---- do some checks ----

    return "recharge"
    }
```

Then when the jsp is loaded, it has the parameters needed to know what to show / hide.
If you submit on the jsp, it goes to another function and does some ops. , then return the same jsp with some url parameters.

All links to the app are like :

```
<a href = <c:url value="/mobilesite/recharge"/>
```

This seems to happen only if i submit the form in the JSP (the url changes).
I need those parameters though, so i can't lose them. But i want if the user leaves the page and clicks again to go to the app, all the rendering part to be computed again.
Any ideas how could i get past this ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: Firebug won't show the request when the link is clicked too.

Comment: Show how you did *"I tried response.setHeader with no-cache and other solutions to disable browser caching"*. Perhaps you just did it wrong. E.g. wrong/incomplete headers or on the wrong response.

Comment: At the beginning of the method i have response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");  
     response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");  
     response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1); then at the end i return my jsp.. i think it might be a spring / weblogic config problem though..